# Alert Dialog embedded buttton is not clicking in Android Java

Tags: android, button, click, android-alertdialog

Am trying to click on a button i just added to an AlertDialog but its not responding. The button is on a layout file in the resources folder and then i added this layout to the AlertDialog via the Builder method `setView()`
I accessed the same Button via my mainactivity after inflating a random view with the layout and set an `OnClickListener` but its still not working
Here is detail code of what i have tried so far
Layout containing the button

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <Button android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="@drawable/round2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:drawablePadding="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
             />
</Linearlayout>
```

Then in my MainActivity.class, i access the button this way

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
   Button submit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         //inflate layout containing button 
         datView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.data_entry,null);
         //access button
         submit=datView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
         //set event listener
         submit.setOnClickListener(this);
         }
     //the interface
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        check();

    }
        //custom method check
     private void check(){
       Toast.makeText(this,"Registering data into database",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
}
```

Despite all that the toast does not show on clicking the button, please help

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `android:onClick = "check"` in the button in your xml, and also create a method in your `MainActivity` called `public void check(View view){...}` with the toast inside of it